# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update [Due to Unique Constraint]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, unique-constraint

Error:
**org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update**

**java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '24-0-es_reservation_detail' for key 'questionId_referenceId_referenceType'**

I am going to save reservation object. This reservation object contains collection of reservaitonDetails objects and each reservation detail object contains collection of questionAnswers Objects.

The main problem is unique constraint on questionAnswer table

```
Unqiue Constraint: question_id, reference_id, reference_type.
```

When system save reservation object: system first save reservation, then collection of reservation details and then all its question answers with 0 (reference_id). While adding question with 0 reference id, system throws exception because unique constraint is violated.

ReservationDetail.hbm.xml

```
.............
.............
<set name="questionAnswers" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" where="reference_type = 'es_reservation_detail'">
        <key column="reference_id"/>
        <one-to-many class=".....QuestionAnswerDTO" />
    </set>
.............
.............
```

Example:

If we save collection on reservation details

```
1. insert into reservation......... (reservation id = 1)

2. insert into reservation_detail.......   (reservation detail id = 1)
3. insert into reservation_detail.......   (reservation detail id = 2)

4. insert into question_answer..... (referece_type='RD' referece_id=0, question_id =1) - For Reservation Detail id =  1
5. insert into question_answer..... (referece_type='RD' referece_id=0, question_id =1) - For Reservation Detail id =  1

6. update reservation_detail set reservation_id = ? where reservation_detail_id = ? (reservation_id = 1, reservation_detail_id = 1)
7. update reservation_detail set reservation_id = ? where reservation_detail_id = ? (reservation_id = 1, reservation_detail_id = 2)

8. update question_answer set reference_id = ? where question_answer_id = ? (reference_id = 1 and question_answer_id =1)
9. update question_answer set reference_id = ? where question_answer_id = ? (reference_id = 2 and question_answer_id =2)
```

When system will execute point (5) script. System will through constraint violation exception.

**Is there any way that hibernate update reference_id in question_answer (table)  immediately before creating next insert query.**

**Script 8 must run after 4th script**

**Script 9 must run after 5th script**

Comment: what is the generator type you are using, it seems , id is not getting incremented, on question and reference entity

Comment: As i have read hibernate documents. Hibernate first insert children objects (questionAnswer) with null or 0 reference and then hibernate executes update query (see the 8 and 9 script).

Comment: two different objects cant have same identifier, i dont know where you got the point, is question_id and reference_id are composite keys?

Comment: (question_id, reference_id, reference_type) is the composite key for table question_asnwer

Comment: I am using "identity" generator in reservation detail hbm mapping.

Comment: what is the relationship between reference and question_answer table, many to many?

Comment: one to many relationship between question_answer and reservation_detail. (One - reservation_detail : many : question_answer). reference_id (column) in table (question_answer) is foreign key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiberate `cascade` option insert child objects with foreign key if you have correctly mapped Parent Class in child mapping. If you have not mapped Parent Class in child mapping but as `Integer` `reference_id`, then foreign key will be updated using separate update query:

```
 update question_answer set reference_id = ? where question_answer_id = ?
```

If you cannot specify Parent class object in Child mapping, then you can use a workaround. You can set `reference_id` as `null` allowed (on table) and you need to set `referenceId=null;` in child object. Then Hibernate cascade will insert child objects will `null` foreign key, and next call update query to set `referenceId` generated foreign key.

Note: `null` values in unique column are not considered as duplicate values if appeared more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you did not define In QuestionAnswerDTO entity a reference back to master entity, which is ReservationDetails. You should configure a @MAnyToOne in QuestionAnswerDTO, that has as @JoinColumn "reference_id" something like that

```
@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="persistence_id")
 private ReservationDetail reservationDetail;
```

and then set reservationDetail property to the actual ReservationDetail object to which it belongs.

Then JPA will know that it needs to populate reference_id with a reference to REservationDetails. Otherwise it considers it as any other field

Comment: Basically there is not referencing issue. This issue is coming with sequence of scripts which is creating by hibernate. I need to update reference id immediately after insertion. But hibernate generate update scripts after all insertion (As mentioned in question.)

Comment: hibernate is generating the scripts based on your entity configurations and the relations between them. As long as you configure properly all relations, you don't have to intervene in what Hibernate is doing at SQL level. Hibernate will generate the scripts in such way to optimize the interaction with the database.